# How to check is url from namespace

Tags: django

I register all my api urls like this:

```
url(r'^api/v2/', include("core.api_v2_urls", namespace="api")),
```

I need to check if a given url is a api url.

Can I use namespace to define it? How?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Of course you could check if a given url is part of all the api urls, but that is not very DRY...

That would work like this in the template:

```
{% url 'firsturl' as first_url %}
{% if request.get_full_path == first_url %}
...do something...
{% endif %}
```

I hope somebody finds a better answer! Actually I'm using this quite a lot now, and it is working fine :)